# Best practices to creating ng shared module

Tags: javascript, angular, font-awesome, angular-ngmodel, shared-module

I want to finally introduce different NgModules into the app. Currently we have one big `AppModule` that has everything, and for our new feature/page we want to create a new module. However, the question arises considering shared modules, components, fontawesome icons. What is the best way to share them?

Here is a snippet of the current `AppModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ... a lot more components here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    .. more imports here
  ],
  providers: (
    [
      TitleCasePipe,
      TranslocoDatePipe,
    ]
  )
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
 

  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
   //  FONTAWESOME_ICONS is a const array with long list of icons
    FONTAWESOME_ICONS.forEach((icon) => {
      library.addIcons(icon)
    })
  }
}
```

It is ugly I know. Now with the new module `VendorsModule` , I need to export the share components, modules into a `SharedModule` so I can import it in both `AppModule`and  `VendorsModule`.
Here is the `SharedModule` I attempted

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DomainComponent,
    .. more components
  ],
  imports: [
    ApiModule,
    .. more modules
  ],
  providers: (
    [
      TitleCasePipe,
      TranslocoDatePipe,
    ]
  )
  exports: [
   .. all the shared components and modules
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {

  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    FONTAWESOME_ICONS.forEach((icon) => {
      library.addIcons(icon)
    })
  }
}
```

Here is `AppModule` after using `SharedModule`.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .. other app components
  ],
  imports: [SharedModule, VendorsModule, BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is `VendorsModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [VendorsComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule],
  exports: [VendorsComponent],
})
export class VendorsModule {}
```

My concern is,
Is it efficient to have to import `SharedModule` in each new introduced module (cause I will defiantly need some of the shared components, icons), even though `SharedModule` includes components and fontawesome icons that may not be relevant to that module.

I have looked at several articles regarding shared modules but they seem to introduce only the basic use case.

This is more of a side question, I am not sure if this is the best way to import fontawesome icons (not-free) into the app.

Comment: If you need all components included inside sharedModule inside any other module, then its good to go with sharded module, But, If you want some in one module, and some in other module, then it will increase bundle size for you unnecessarily

Comment: I am having another issue now that I try to lazy-load the new module. It complains that some modules are imported twice, but when I remove the module from the `SharedModule` into `AppModule`, then the components in the SharedModule starting giving bunch of errors that it is missing imports. e.g. async pipe in known. I am not sure where the imports should go then?

Comment: Can you share  your live working demo ?

Comment: I figured it out, I had some missing imports :)

Comment: Happy that you have figured it out. I am looking for work in angular related work, If you have or any reference then it will be more hlepful to me right now. Here is my email ID `grdtechlab@gmail.com`